# Error while reading dump file in DebugDiag Analysis

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, debug-diagnostic-tool

I have installed DebugDiag Tool to monitor high CPU usage at the windows server.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210

I am getting following error while analysing dump files generated by DebugDiag Collection tool.

---

### No report file was generated

An error occurred while generating the analysis report
Exception: Type:    COMException
Message:    Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
StackTrace:    at DebugDiag.DbgLib.DbgControlClass_Legacy.OpenDump(String DumpPath, String SymbolPath, String ImagePath, Object pProgress)
at DebugDiag.DotNet.NetDbgObj.OpenDump(String dumpPath, String symbolPath, String imagePath, Object pProgress, Boolean throwOnBitnessMismatch, Boolean loadClrRuntime, Boolean loadClrHeap)

at DebugDiag.DotNet.NetDbgObj.GetDumpFileType(String dumpFile, String symbolPath)

at DebugDiag.DotNet.NetAnalyzer.AddDumpFile(String dumpFile, String symbolPath)

at DebugDiag.DotNet.NetAnalyzer.AddDumpFiles(List`1 dumpFiles, String symbolPath)

at DebugDiag.Analysis.AnalyzerClient.RunAnalysisAsyncInternal(NetProgress progress, String symbolPath, String imagePath, List`1 dumpFiles, List`1 analysisRules, String reportFileDirectoryOrFullPath, Boolean IncludeSourceAndLineInformationInAnalysisReports, Boolean SetContextOnCrashDumps, Boolean DoHangAnalysisOnCrashDumps, Boolean IncludeHttpHeadersInClientConns, SynchronizationContext synchContext, Boolean ExcludeIdenticalStacks, Boolean IncludeInstructionPointerInAnalysisReports)